# How to set multiple ClientCustomerId in Google Adwords API in php?

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I have multiple client Id (i.e. xxx-xxx-xxxx) under one main account. I can access API by using one account id (xxx-xxx-xxxx) and get the API response. 
But in my current application I need to get API response of multiple account id (i.e. xxx-xxx-xxxx, yyy-yyy-yyyy). Actually I want to avoid the API call in loop of multiple account id.

Now in my php library  I can set one account that is

```
$user = new AdWordsUser();
$user->SetClientCustomerId($clientId);
```

Is there any way, so that I can set multiple account and get data in one single API call in google adwords ?

Answer (score 1):

The SetClientCustomerId($clientId); method only accepts 1 parameter (1 client id), so no, you can't set multiple accounts and get data in one single API call.